# Is there an equivalent to jQuery.on for Firefox addons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, jquery-on

Is there anything equivalent to jQuery's `.on` functionality, for chrome-level javascript? I want a Firefox addon to add events on a large number of elements in a document in chrome context. Looping and adding eventlisteners sounds slow and wouldn't update on change, and importing jQuery into chrome code sounds unsupported and bloated. I read through the .on function [in the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L730), but I'm not quite sure how it works.

Comment: it works via event propagation (bubbling).

Comment: How could I forget... So instead of `$('bigelement').on('click','.things',function)`, the recommended equivalent is `bigelement.addEventListener('click',function(e) { check e.target is .things ... })` ?

Comment: Actually, it may need to keep getting parentNode, though, to check if it is what you're wanting an event for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have fine performance while processing events of huge amount of elements, you may `addEventListener`s to the top elements. Do not forget to use e.target in this case.

Just to answer the question. Thanks kirilloid.

Answer (score 0):

Use zepto!

Zepto.js supports $.on()

Comment: Looks neat, but I doubt it's recommended for use in addons. I noticed a warning on AMO validator that warned about "innerHTML", saying for performance it should be using createElement etc., and jQuery is slower/slow as innerHTML.